# InstallAware 18 VS InstallShield 2013

Tags: installshield, setup-project

We are planning to create setup file for our project, our research lead us to:

- InstallAwere 18
- InstallShield 2013

We have some requirements that must be supported:

1. Windows Server 2012
2. Able to run other MSI/EXE
3. Full support for patches/updates
4. Run Powershell script
5. Database support (Create db/Execute sp)
6. Web site deployment

Nice to have:
 - Windows features identification (run installation if necessary) 
 - Web installer (small package that will download all the necessary components)

Did I miss any other product on the market that can support all this? And the final question is what would you suggest for our setup package between these two? 
Firsthand experience would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is another application you can use for creating setup packages. It is [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

I'm using it for several years and it is really easy to use. I think it can help you with all of your requirements. They also have a great support team.

Answer (score 0):

i think that InstallAware is more power full than InstallShield 
look: http://www.installaware.com/compare-with-otherinstall-tools.htm